# Working From home for a small company vs In office for a Medium sized company

Tags: company-culture, work-life-balance, software-development, layoff

I was looking for some insight with other that may have had to make a decision like mine.

I currently have an opportunity in front of me that will allow me to work from home for a small to medium sized consulting company for a Software Engineer role.

I've done my homework and have been talking with them for about 2 months now. We had early communications the first two weeks than about 2 week in-between there was little communication as they said they were organizing their product road map before bringing someone on.

My current job is is good, not great with a company who's been around about 20+ years and is currently gobbling up other companies and starting to make bigger strides in the market. Aside from that I do not have a good working relationship with my boss for many reasons and hes quite the micromanger. We also had layoffs about 7 weeks ago, about the same time I started talking with this smaller company.

I'm two years into being a developer and six total from graduated where I spent the first four consulting and coding from graduating.

There are many aspects of not jumping on this smaller company so quickly, mainly my concern with our two week communication breakdown, its a smaller company so I expect to have many hats and have a lot of freedom in what I am doing.

I'm looking for opinions on smaller companies, working from home and the security that may come with my current company assuming we do not have more layoffs.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: This is asking advice about what to do, so it isn't answerable here. My 2 pennies: it totally depends on you: I for instance cannot work from home. Many other would prefer working from home. It is up to you.

Comment: A small company requires a lot of self motivation, and knowledge of how things should be done. As a junior developer, are you confident you have these things?

Answer (score 2):

Pros of working from home are many, but so are the cons. It's not as easy as it seems. At home you have plenty of distractions and unless you have a strong work ethic most people I know (including myself) become untidy with things like working hours and timeframes.

Generally solid careers are built through in office jobs where you're more than a digital presence and can showcase your skills better to the people who matter, and there is a social aspect to teamwork as well as a professional one.

You need to decide which form of work you are most suited to, and you need to look closely at any company who is looking for workers to work from home, a lot of those are dodgy and it's very easy to mess with a remote worker over money.